# I can't add a tag because I have less than 1500 reputation points

Tags: support, tags

I wanted to ask a question about a new framework, and that framework doesn't have a tag on Stack Overflow.

I added the tag name inside the tags field, but I couldn't add the question because I can't create tags.

What can I do if I want to add tag when I have less than 1500 reputation points?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does a low-rep user ask for a new tag to be created?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274706/how-does-a-low-rep-user-ask-for-a-new-tag-to-be-created)

Comment: @tepples, no this isn't the duplicate. This was posted before that question.

Comment: @AshishAhuja Duplicate status in Stack Exchange depends on which question has better answers, not which has an earlier post date. Old questions are routinely closed as dupes of new ones, especially new "canonical" questions intended to consolidate dupes. See [How should duplicate questions be handled?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/229356) and [What is a canonical question/answer, and what is their purpose?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291994/2738262).

Answer (score 72, accepted):

1. Add a comment to the question indicating what tag you would have liked to add.
2. Raise a question on meta (which is what you've done).

If someone with more than 1,500 rep agrees then they'll add the tag.

Try not to add the commentary about the tag to the question itself. That's not necessary.

Comment: In addition, if you want to create a tag but lack the rep, you should also propose some textual description for it here on meta.