# Create Licode tag suggestion

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonym-process

According to Question:[I can't add a tag because I have less than 1500 reputation points](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260631/i-cant-add-a-tag-because-i-have-less-than-1500-reputation-points).

I want to suggest adding a [Licode](http://lynckia.com/licode/) tag on Stack Overflow.

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24340133/licode-erizo-stream-video-frame-quality) and I can't create tags.

Description:

- [Licode](http://lynckia.com/licode/) is an Open Source WebRTC Communications Platform.
- It is for building  videoconference/chat rooms.
- It is based on WebRTC technologies.
- It provides a development of videoconference features based on
  HTML5.

[Architecture](http://lynckia.com/licode/architecture.html), [Client API](http://lynckia.com/licode/client-api.html), [Server API](http://lynckia.com/licode/server-api.html).

Comment: Done, can you create a tag excerpt for it?

Comment: @ben thanks , I would like to yes I can suggest one.

Comment: @ben after adding the tag you think this question (create licode tag suggestion ) should get removed?

Comment: You could self answer if Ben doesn't want to answer. I see no need to get this question removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Ben for creating the tag.

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/licode/info