# How does a low-rep user ask for a new tag to be created?

Tags: support, tags

I and many others use a tool called AnyLogic that runs on Java. The community lacks a good channel for asking questions; their current approach is to use a group on LinkedIn. I know several key people in this community, and I'd like to start directing them here. While most of the community's questions will be Java-oriented, the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag isn't good enough for them because many of their questions are AnyLogic-specific. An [anylogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anylogic) tag would be very helpful to aggregate their questions and answers, and to help the AnyLogic support staff monitor Stack Overflow for questions. Unfortunately, I nor the AnyLogic staff (AFAIK) have enough rep to create an [anylogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anylogic) tag. How do I, but a lowly long-time but low-rep user, request that this tag be created?

Comment: Maybe the [java chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/java)?

Comment: Just make sure the new tag is named after the library or framework, not the company (or sometimes company-framework, if the framework name wouldn't be unique).  Some names actually are both the company and the major product, but that situation is often transient.

Comment: See [When is tag creation appropriate, and how does it work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252944)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Asking here works as well as anywhere. [Go create a tag wiki for this now, and then apply it to all the other questions that need it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/anylogic)

Comment: Thank you! I'll be sure to do that (and I'll let the AnyLogic team know)

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged now as [tag:status-complete]?

Comment: It's a support question, @cybermonkey - there's usually no need to "complete" them apart from someone (anyone!) posting an answer.