# Can we clean up Eclipse "Error: Could not find or load main class"?

Tags: discussion, clean-up, canonical

Let me start by saying *I don't know exactly what we should do here*.

This search: [[eclipse] "Could not find or load main class" is:question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Beclipse%5D+%22Could+not+find+or+load+main+class%22+is%3Aquestion) returns 104 questions. Note that the phrase is in quotes here.

Two of them (one is duplicate of the other) have over 90k views each:

- [Eclipse "Error: Could not find or load main class"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235827/eclipse-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class?s=1|0.0000) (30 answers not counting deleted)
- [Eclipse Error: Could not find or load main class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16334625/eclipse-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class?s=2|0.0000) (9 answers not counting deleted)

These questions have so... many... different... answers. So many of them are short, too, not necessarily bad, but not very useful. For example:

> I run into the same problem, but in my case it was caused by missing (empty) source folder (it exists in original project, but not in GIT repository because it's empty).
>
> After creating the missing folder everything works.

And:

> I had the same problem. Spent few hours and finally changed my workspace back to local folder and everything works now. Maybe saves some time for others. Jon

And:

> Just go to your Package Explorer and press F5, or for some laptops fn+F5. The reason is that eclipse thinks that the files are somewhere, but the files are actually somewhere else. By refreshing it, you put them both on the same page. Don't worry, you won't lose anything, but if you want to be extra careful, just back up the files from your java projects folder to somewhere safe.

And:

> I found other solution in my case this problem: `Eclipse->Preferences->Java->Installed JRE` then press button Search. Select folder in Linux `/usr` then Eclipse found all JVM.
>
> **Select another JVM too current**. It is solved for my case.

And:

> I faced the same error, the error was in one of the imported external jars. After removing that jar project worked for me.

And:

> Follow The Steps it Works for me : 1.Remove Configure build path from eclipse(Build Path) 2.Refresh 3.add configure Build Path->Source->add Folder->check src ok.

And on and on and on, not just in these two questions but in the 100 others too.

I can't clean this up by myself, I don't want to flag one and leave it between me and a single moderator; I want to involve the community.

Perhaps we should merge the two biggest questions, and make a single list answer of all the different approaches to trying to solve this problem, and wikilock it? I don't even know...

Comment: There's another issue at hand here.  The answers encompass all of the similar problems that others have run into, which may *wildly* diverge from the original problem.  The question then becomes, do we want one of these questions to become a catch-all and have different answers for the different scenarios, or do we want the focus to become laser-like, and we approach the question with a scalpel?  (Aside:  the duplicate on the top two questions may need to be reversed.)

Comment: @Makoto these are all great questions. If I knew the answers to any of them, there would be a lot less "I don't know" in my question.

Comment: In that case, let's start by focusing on the two top answers.  Is one more definitively helpful/useful than the other in this day and age?  Personally the thought of *using* Eclipse makes my skin crawl, but installing a copy of it to verify some things wouldn't hurt...

Comment: @Makoto: My general philosophy is that answers that guess at some variant of the problem based on a) the question and b) whatever else they personally experienced in additional symptoms aren't very useful and should be separated out: otherwise, they're really just micro-self-answered questions stuck in the answer box.

Comment: [What is a canonical question/answer, and what is their purpose?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291992/what-is-a-canonical-question-answer-and-what-is-their-purpose) It looks like some of the answers might be too long to be summarized well enough into a single post, so perhaps having a master answer with a brief summary of each solution with a link to a separate answer (on the same page) that elaborates on that one (not sure whether doing this is recommended).

Comment: Please do include the text "I have the same problem" or some variant at the beginning of each section though. </sarcasm>

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan [Searching for that text with SEDE](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302110/please-help-me-to-understand-lqp-flagging?cb=1) is how I stumbled upon this in the first place

Comment: *"There is a common trend in questions there: the OP says "my X hurts when I do Y", and nobody knows exactly why. So people who also had pain in X when doing Y (perhaps for a completely different reason) post their answers: I did Z and it helped me. They don't necessarily know why Z helped."* -- [Normal Human](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3807476#3807476) The worst part is that most answers don't explain the reason of *why* the solution, umm, solved the problem for them.

Comment: @Braiam That is also a huge part of the reason why I don't know what we should do here.

Comment: So, in summary: We should create a canonical Q&A thread where the canonical answer is simply "Install a different IDE, and this problem goes away".

Comment: @Yakk oh, the rofls...

Comment: If a single question has many correct answers, doesn't that mean the question is too broad to begin with?

Comment: @Cypher The idea is that it would be [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/1768232)

Comment: I understand that, but there is a clear way to debug NullPointerExceptions while there isn't exactly a clear way to fix this error message that pops up in Eclipse when *something* is broken. That error message is more of a symptom than a cause, and there can be many different reasons why (as seen with all of the varying answers). It just seems to me that the answer itself is going to be huge, vague, and not very helpful. It's a bit like trying to explain why Windows XP erupts with BSODs sometimes. There are a lot of reasons, none of them very simple to explain, debug, and fix. :)

Comment: @Cypher you hit the nail on the head. The main reason why most answers are so vague and don't explain why is because the root cause is not discovered, documented and solved; only by trying some random stuff the symptom is made to go away. In fact I'd be surprised that when someone says "I tried X and it went away, don't know why" - that X was actually the thing that made it go away; it might have been any number of other random acts that were attempted at the same time that did it, but are left unmentioned.

Answer (score 10):

I'd say we should create a (new) [canonical Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291992/what-is-a-canonical-question-answer-and-what-is-their-purpose) summarizing all the possible causes.

---

It looks like some of the answers might be too long to be summarized well enough into a single post, so perhaps having a master answer with a brief summary of each solution with a link to a separate answer (on the same page) that elaborates on that one (not sure whether doing this is recommended), as in:

> Q: Why...
>
> (Accepted) A1: Here are some possible causes:
>
> - You have a missing empty folder, which can be fixed by manually creating said folder. (link to A2)
> - The project is stale, which can be fixed by refreshing it from the Package Explorer. (link to A3)
> - ...
>
> A2: You have a missing empty source folder. One possible way this could happen is the GIT repository not creating the directory which existed in the original project because it's empty. ...
>
> A3: The project is stale. Go to your Package Explorer and press F5 to refresh it, or for some laptops fn+F5. ...

---

Unless someone who knows everything about everything wants to just go ahead and create a canonical Q&A all by themselves, with all the already posted solutions and also elaborate on the reason behind each, I suggest:

1. We compile a complete list of useful and distinct answers and posts them (here, as an answer?), while noting which needs attention. This could be done by one person, or someone can just start one, noting which questions they have processed, and anyone can add onto that list.
2. The community tries to edit all the answers that need attention, adding additional details as required, and modifying the above list as they go. This could also involve asking answerers to elaborate on their own answers using comments.
3. Once few enough attention-requiring answers remain, someone can create a canonical Q&A. If there are still attention-requiring answers, these should perhaps be posted separately in the Q&A to make it clear that they need attention (for example, by having it in a separate section at the end of the master answer suggested above).

---

Why not use one of the existing questions?

Because this would likely involve a rewrite of the question (which the asker may not be happy with and revert a few times), many of the answers might be better off not there (duplicates, for example), answerers may not be happy with the necessary edits to make it a good answer (and revert the edits a few times) and being able to accept the master answer so it shows up on top would be good (just make sure **someone else posts the master answer** because accepting your own answer doesn't make it show up on top).

Answer (score 2):

If someone ask the question *"**Why** does Eclipse throw 'Could not find or load main class'"* instead of *"'Could not find or load main class' fix pls"* and list the common causes without operative solutions and an array of "How do I apply X" where X is a solution, I could get behind that.

Something like this:

- Q: Why does Eclipse throw 'Could not find or load main class'

  - A: The project is staled, you need to refresh it
  - A: Your source is probably missing, you need to find it
  - A: etc.

This allows new answers to be added, if new causes appears, and then on a separated Q&A:

- Q: How do I refresh a project?

  - A: Click refresh.

Which allows searching for these tasks independently of the problem the user is facing. Example, if refreshing a project helps with several problems, the affected users would find the how-to, once they know the cause.

Comment: Surely you're proposing editing one of the two top answers into this, and not making a fresh question, right?

Comment: @durron597 whatever works the best, but I'm not a fan of hijacking existing questions with tons of answers.

Comment: Consider the [revision history of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/218384/revisions)

Comment: @durron597 if I'm reading that correctly, the first and foremost questions was "what this error means", contrary to what the questions you posted asks. That's why asking the right questions right away can save the day, nuances matters.