# What are the rules relevant to duplicate, canonical and reopened questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

This user marked this Question

- [Run JavaScript promises in order. One after the other ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44422851/run-javascript-promises-in-order-one-after-the-other-ends)

as a duplicate of the following questions

- [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)
- [Javascript - Can't get the value of the function outside of it, getting undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43965421)
- [What is the point of promises in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43982774/what-is-the-point-of-promises-in-javascript)

and subsequently composed a canonical Question/Answer

- [Why is value undefined at .then() chained to Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44439596/why-is-value-undefined-at-then-chained-to-promise/)

to address the oft posed question as to why a value is

- `undefined` when logged outside of the `Promise` chain
- `undefined` at chained `.then()` callback function
- the chained `.then()` does not appear to wait for the `Promise` result within a function call; or
- the chained `.then()` does not appear to wait for a fulfilled `Promise` from previous `.then()`

The purpose of the canonical is to refer to the Question/Answer when the inquiry arises again, to avoid the need to simply state

- "no value or `Promise` is `return`ed from the function call"; or
- "no value or `Promise` is `return`ed from preceding `.then()`"

However, the duplicate Question has been reopened. OP of the Question answered own Question by stating, in pertinent part,

> Based on the comments. Here is the version works. A simple return is
>   missing from original codes

which is the substantial Answer at the canonical Question

> Because no `Promise` or other value is returned from `.then()` chained
>   to `Promise` constructor.

leading to the present inquiry.

What are the rules relevant to duplicate Questions being reopened where there is clearly

a) an existing Answer to the new Question?

b) a subsequent canonical Question/Answer is posted which addresses and provides solutions for not only the current inquiry, but the topic in general?

Do the rules provide for a Question marked as duplicate to be reopened where the re-opening of the new Question results in two or more Question on the exact same topic having the exact same Answer?

Should users simply not mark new questions as duplicates of previous Questions? And continue providing the same Answer at each new Question where a value is not `return`ed from a function call or previous `.then()`.

That is, *"because no value is `return`ed from the function or `.then()`"*, should be the Answer reproduced multiple times for exact same inquiry when the Question arises again?

What is the ultimate integrity of the duplicate procedure based on? Or is there no consistent integrity to the procedure and rules therefor?

Related: [What is a canonical question/answer, and what is their purpose?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291992)

Comment: At very least, don't duplicate content to yet another Q/A under the guise of it being "canonical".

Answer (score -8, accepted):

The fact is that there are not any consistent rules or standards relevant to duplicate, canonical or reopened questions.

Duplicate questions and answers exist at stackoverflow.com. Not only do duplicate questions and answers exist, viewers are aware of and acknowledge the fact the duplicate questions and answers exist.

Canonical question/answers are just that. A user should not expect that other users will view the question/answer as beneficial.

Questions are closed and reopened frequently.

The vote to or designation of "duplicate", "canonical", and "reopen" a Question is based solely on the opinion of the individual viewer of the Question.

Answer (score 8):

If a user simply disagrees with you that the question is a duplicate, then you can simply cast your own vote to close, again, to reflect your own opinion.  Some people simply are *going* to disagree over whether or not questions are duplicates, and that's okay.

If you have evidence to support the assertion that a user reopened the question *knowing full well that the duplicate answered it*, meaning that they didn't reopen the question in good faith, then that would be abusive behavior, and in such a case you'd want to flag for moderator attention explaining why you believe someone was reopening a question *that they honestly felt was answered by the duplicate*, rather than simply because they disagree with you over whether the duplicate(s) answer it.  Keep in mind that this is a difficult thing to prove, so you should have fairly compelling evidence to include in your flag if you're doing this, and not just "the question looks like a duplicate to me even though they reopened it".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146283/discussion-on-answer-by-servy-what-are-the-rules-relevant-to-duplicate-canonica).

Comment: @Servy _"If a user simply disagrees with you that the question is a duplicate, then you can simply cast your own vote to close again to reflect your own opinion"_ Is there a span of time following initial original close vote where that is not possible? _"You voted to close this question yesterday"_

Comment: @guest271314 If you've already cast your own close vote, then you will not be able to do so again.  You've had your say.

Comment: @Servy Then that portion of your Answer is not accurate, correct?

Comment: @guest271314 No, it's entirely accurate.  If you feel that someone has reopened a question that you feel should be closed, you can vote to close it.  If you've *already* voted to close it then you've already had your say.  You feel the question should be closed, they feel it should be open.  Other people can weigh in as well, and the question will eventually end up where the community consensus lies.

Comment: @Servy Then why is "again" in the sentence? _"cast your own vote to close again"_

Comment: The commas still do not provide clarity.

Comment: @guest271314 To say that your vote to close is reflecting your own opinion, just as the other user's vote to reopen is their own opinion, rather than to indicate that it would be a second vote.

Comment: Why do you not directly say "you can only vote to close once"? Or similar construct. To avoid confusion.

Comment: @guest271314 Because the question is not asking about close vote rules, including off topic information detracts from the answer, and if someone is unaware that they can't vote multiple times then they'll get a nice error message explaining the rule to them if they try to vote a second time.

Comment: The Question is relevant to closed votes or questions, a Question cannot cannot be "reopened" unless users have "voted" to "close" the Question. In any event, it is your Answer.

Comment: @guest271314 Discussing every possible feature, or guideline, or etiquette, or other issue related to closure would require hundreds of pages of text.  One simply cannot discuss *everything* related to closure on every question that has something to do with closure.  You asked what you should do if someone votes to reopen a question that you think should be closed, so the answer focuses on that, and *only* that.

Comment: @Servy Yes, instead of discussing the minutia of the details, we encourage hundreds of further questions _"why the expected value at `.then()` is `undefined`?_ and hundreds of answers stating _"Because no `Promise` or other value is returned from `.then()` chained to `Promise` constructor."_ Fair enough. The balance, or imbalance, depending on perspective, is achieved one way or the other.

Comment: @guest271314 I mean, if you're the only person that thinks that those questions don't have relevant differences, sure.  If more people (with the appropriate privileges) feel that there are no relevant differences, then no.