# What do we do with future posts that could benefit from bad but historic questions?

Tags: discussion

So this came from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56463815/i-need-help-resolving-this-sql-query?noredirect=1#comment99520113_56463815) and essentially it raises a good question of what do we do with new posts that could benefit from these historic questions?

For example, I see a lot of **Parse Syntax Error** within the PHP tag, and for the most part, I just mark as a dupe, linking it to [this historic question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them/18092318).

It's my understanding is that, if this question was asked today (without any other historic record) then it would probably get closed. So my question is, should I still be linking and flagging new posts to these older historic questions that would be closed by today's standards?

Comment: Wow, that dupe target ["What does the * asterisk mean in a mysql statement?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824414/what-does-the-asterisk-mean-in-a-mysql-statement) is laughably bad, although it is an accurate duplicate

Comment: There's been various attempts to build a "knowledge base" over the years which would address these non-question/non-answer entries, most recently the ["documentation" feature](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/07/21/introducing-stack-overflow-documentation-beta/).

Comment: @DavyM my point.. what's the best thing to do? haha

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe. This is about a specific kind of very-broad canonical question (Tell me all about X, How to fix all sorts of X errors, The Definitive Guide to X) that was very popular in the past but has become disfavored. *Narrow* canonical questions (How do I fix this very common specific Reticulated Spline Not Found error when connecting to a UNIX server using MatrixScript slot notation?) are still fine here.

Answer (score 5):

I'm opposed to using these questions as dupes as-is.

I like the *idea* of these old canonical questions, but I fear that they present the wrong example for users today. The more we direct new users to these questions, the more we portray the idea that it's ok to post *new* questions along these lines. This is not theoretical - about a year or two ago I saw a user post a "The Definitive Language X Book Guide and List" question, *explicitly* stating that they intended the question to be the Language X equivalent of [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/6471538) , which dates all the way back to *2008*. As you might expect, *their* question was very poorly-received and was downvoted and closed (as an off-topic resource request question) within the hour.

What do we do? We have two main options:

- Let these old broad questions die a slow death, and do not show them to new users until we are certain that they understand how things work *today*.
- Close and/or historical lock these old questions, so that users referred to them can see that they should not create their own.

Comment: I'm not sure I would handle the question mentioned by the OP the same as the C++ book list. The book list sprung up organically in 2008, and indeed is a remnant of the carefree early months of SO. That other question, however, is from 2013, which is significantly later in the evolution of SO, and was manifestly created as a canonical/curation resource.

Comment: "Let these old broad questions die a slow death" --> but they're generally **not** doing so. Many of them are an upvote-fest of egregious proportion. Also regarding "how things work *today* --> <rant>unfortunately we've been observing what in lack of other words, I'd call an intentional sabotage operation on SO quality guidelines, emanating from none other than SE the company, supposedly caving in to clueless, "woke" user bases but seemingly rather aimed at maximizing ad revenue. So I fear "how things work today" and implied quality guidelines may not be a usable metric for long. </rant>

Answer (score 2):

The [duplicate target suggested by gnat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291992/2751851) provides relevant framing for this discussion. The question we are talking about is a *canonical*, or, as the answer over there puts it, "a broad question/answer [set] that is intended to be a duplicate target for commonly asked questions". In my view, the crucial point here is that we are not considering a mere historical artefact from the formative days of Stack Overflow (by the way, [it was created in August 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18050071/1), around the time the site turned five), but a post that was manifestly created as a tool for curation.

Now, it might be the case that this specific tool is not as efficient as one might like. Perhaps a canonical structured in a different manner would be more useful as a duplicate target -- and, given you do use it as a target, you likely have a few things to say on the matter. While that would be a perfectly reasonable discussion to hold, it is not what you are putting on the table here, if I understand it correctly. Quoting a comment of yours:

> I get their purpose, but how can higher rep users promote better asking of questions when these historic questions, which are highly upvoted etc., are of bad question-quali.. feels like it goes against the point of how-to-ask when we use these questions as dupe targets

The concern seems to be with setting a bad example, or, as in [Robert Columbia's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385784/2751851), giving users arguments to defend problematic questions. On that, I'd say that anyone who uses a canonical Q&A which is manifestly a purpose-built tool for curation to argue in support of an ordinary question that skirts the guidelines is comparing apples and oranges. From this perspective, using the canonical as a target is not a mistake; adapting curation practices to conform to flawed arguments is.

---

On a final note, there is another point worth addressing in that comment I quoted:

> and it's not just the canonical questions, view the linked question and my dupe target

If you think a potential duplicate target -- old, popular, highly upvoted, or whatever it might be -- is irredeemably not good enough as a target, don't use it. Find an alternative target; if you can't find one, consider answering the question so that there will be a good enough target in the future, or just let it be. I, for one, have closed questions against a duplicate of the obvious target question due finding said target too messy to be useful. (Regardless of what I have argued in the first part of this answer -- which was primarily a meta-meta argument -- this also applies to canonicals: if you don't think a canonical, no matter how venerable, is not good enough, don't use it.)

Comment: `not good enough as a target, don't use it.` - then we just leave these questions un-duped when the question/answer is the same?

Comment: @treyBake Yes. For instance, it is better to do nothing than to direct readers to a misleading answer. "Not good enough", of course, is a judgement call that is largely up to the close voter. (I, for one, don't actually think the SQL `*` Q&A you allude to is all that bad as a duplicate target: the Q&A is not too meandering, the answers are correct and, taken as a whole, cover the essentials, and the fact that the question body consists only of a code block can be easily fixed by editing a short explanatory paragraph into it.)

Comment: Not like that - I just mean, if the question itself is bad (dupe-end)? As in, off-topic full stop?

Comment: @treyBake In all likelihood, a duplicate of an off-topic question is off-topic too, and should be closed as such. (Note that, in contrast, a duplicate of a broad question isn't necessarily broad. In such cases, the difference between a purpose-built broad canonical and a broad question that is just messy might kick in.)